# Custom front-end form for adding post - Category problem

Tags: custom-post-types, php, categories, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a `CPT` front-end form for post-adding. It has a title, description, categories, image, and a couple of custom fields connected with `ACF` in the backend.

Everything is working, except categories. Once the form is submitted, categories are not added in the single backend post.

Here is the code part where the categories are looped on the front-end:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'     => 'types',
    'hide_empty'   => false,
    'hierarchical' => 1
);
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

And here is the process:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['post_form'] ) ) {
    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $user_login  = $current_user->user_login;
    $user_id     = $current_user->ID;
    $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $current_user->ID );

    $post_title     = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pas_title'] );
    $post_category  = (int) $_POST['cat'];
    $post_content   = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pas_content'] );
    $post_phone     = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pas_phone'] );
    $post_location  = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pas_location'] );
    $post_price     = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pas_price'] );
    $post_condition = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pas_condition'] );

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'   => $post_title,
        'post_content' => $post_content,
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_name'    => str_replace( ' ', '-', $post_title ),
        'post_type'    => 'ads',
        'post_author'  => $author_name,
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $post_category, 'types' );
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', true );
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'cena', $post_price );
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'lokacija', $post_location );
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'kontakt_telefon', $post_phone );
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'stanje_robe', $post_condition );
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'pas_user_id', $user_id );

    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php' );
    }

    $file_logo = media_handle_upload( 'pas_image', $post_id );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $file_logo );
}
```

I've done it before in the same way where everything worked.

If needed, here is the `CPT` part:

```
class PAS_Cpt {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'pas_cpt_ads' ), 0 );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'pas_cpt_ads_taxonomy' ), 0 );
    }

    /**
     * CPT Oglasi
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function pas_cpt_ads() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'               => __( 'Oglasi' ),
            'singular_name'      => __( 'Oglas' ),
            'menu_name'          => __( 'Oglasi' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'Svi oglasi' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'Pogledaj oglas' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Dodaj novi Oglas' ),
            'add_new'            => __( 'Dodaj novi' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edituj oglas' ),
            'update_item'        => __( 'Ažuriraj oglas' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Pretraži oglas' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'Nije pronađen' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nije pronađen u kanti' )
        );
        $args   = array(
            'label'               => __( 'ads' ),
            'labels'              => $labels,
            'supports'            => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'author',
                'thumbnail',
                'revisions',
                'custom-fields'
            ),
            'public'              => true,
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'can_export'          => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'yarpp_support'       => true,
            'taxonomies'          => array(
                'post_tag'
            ),
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'post',
            'menu_icon'           => __( 'dashicons-megaphone' )
        );
        register_post_type( 'ads', $args );
    }

    /**
     * CPT Oglasi Taxonomy
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function pas_cpt_ads_taxonomy() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Kategorije', 'ads' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Kategorija', 'ads' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Pretraži kategorije' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'Sve kategorije' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent kategorija' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent kategorija:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edituj kategoriju' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Ažuriraj kategoriju' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Dodaj novu kategoriju' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Kategorije' ),
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'types', array( 'ads' ), array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                'slug' => 'type'
            ),
        ) );
    }
}

new PAS_Cpt();
```

I've been struggling with this for two days. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does `wp_set_object_terms` return - it should give a WP_Error object if something's gone wrong

Comment: It's returning `Invalid taxonomy`. But the taxonomy is correct. It's very odd. This approach on another website works perfectly fine.

Comment: OK - Bingo! Look at your `register_post_type` `$args`.... I can only see `post_tag` as a linked taxonomy

Comment: And what should I set? I've tried with `post, ads, types` still the same error.

Comment: Should be an array of values IE `'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'types', 'another_example' ),`  See [`register_post_type()` - Taxonomies](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#taxonomies)